# XPath operator: some child element contains substring

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XML file like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root> 
  <channel> 
    <item> 
      <title>India Wins</title>  
      <cat>Cricket News</cat>  
      <cat>India</cat> 
    </item>  
    <item> 
      <title>Barcelona Wins</title>  
      <cat>Barcelona</cat>  
      <cat>Celta Vigo</cat>  
      <cat>Football</cat> 
    </item>  
    <item> 
      <title>England lost</title>  
      <cat>Cricket</cat>  
      <cat>T20</cat>  
      <cat>England</cat> 
    </item> 
  </channel> 
</root>
```

I want to get the all the titles of Cricket News.
Like my output should be :`India Wins` and `England lost`

So I am running the Xpath Query like that `//*[cat="Cricket"]/title`
It is giving result : `England lost`, which is understandable to me .

But I want do similar thing like `//*[contains(cat,"Cricket")]/title`,so that both the titles of the category `Cricket` and `Cricket News` will come. But it is giving no output .

Also i have ran the Xpath Query in many online Xpath testers and they are giving error message like that

> ERROR - A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first
>   argument of contains()

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, the first argument of `contains()` must not have multiple items.  You need to rewrite your xpath to something like this:

```
//item[cat[contains(.,'Cricket')]]/title/text()
```

Comment: It worked with this : `//item[cat[contains(.,'Cricket')]]/title`